# Почему не стоит возвращать None из функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Я никогда так не делаю. Но знаю, что это антипаттерн. Почему не рекомендуется возвращать из функции None? Есть ли на это PEP8?

Comment: Какое-то странное правило, либо вы его не очень точно передали. Иногда в соответствии с логикой программы из функции как раз None и нужно вернуть. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: @Xander когда-то давно я писал `return None`, но мне за это ударили по рукам. Кажется, что, действительно, не очень хорошо, если в одном случае функция будет возвращать `None`, а в другом -- какой-нибудь тип.

Comment: По-моему это всё чьи-то личные заскоки. В большинстве популярных библиотек есть функции и метода, которые возвращают None. В стандартной библиотеке есть такие функции и методы! В конце концов, зачем в языке существует None, если его не надо использовать? Я за три года работы питонистом первый раз слышу, что так делать нельзя.

Comment: Ерунда какая-то. значение None - это то, то функция _должна_ отдавать по умолчанию.

Comment: @strawdog ок, я вас понял. Спасибо

Comment: @strawdog есть ли в PEP, который регламентирует, для каких целей нужен None?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41634890/5741205

Comment: @MaxU ответ, видимо такой: None возвращать можно. Но его точно нужно возвращать, в случае если возвращается что-нибудь ещё в какой-нибудь ветке функции

Comment: Это зависит от ситуации. Если это процедура, которая никогда (ни в одном месте) ничего не возвращает, то и “return” в ней использовать не нужно. Если функция может вернуть что-то, то есть смысл в том случае если возвращать нечего воспользоваться явным «Return None” для лучшей читабельности

Comment: Для справки: функция которая ничего не возвращает и не имеет слова “Return” в коде все равно возвращает None (неявно)

Comment: Тот, кто вам не рекомендовал возвращать `None`, вероятнее всего имел в виду, что не нужно возвращать его в качестве индикатора ошибки, и лучше вместо этого выбрасывать исключение. Это правда. Например, ваша функция возвращает булево значение, либо `None` если что-то пошло не так. Представляете, насколько велика вероятность ее неправильного использования, если программист не изучит документацию досконально, или просто забудет, что функция может завершиться ошибкой?

Answer (score 1):

Если ссылаться на `PEP8`, то там можно найти, что запрета на возврат `None` как такого нет. И даже больше, [в разделе рекомендаций](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) указано, что функция должна возвращать `None`.

Оригинал:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable):

Перевод:

> Будьте последовательны в возвращаемых выражениях. Либо все операторы return должны возвращать выражение, либо ни одно из них не должно. Если какой-либо оператор return возращает выражение, тогда остальные операторы return, в которых значение не возвращается должны явно устанавливаться как **return None**, а явный оператор return должен присутствовать в конце функции:

Пример корректного и не верного применения оттуда же:

```py
# Correct:

def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return None

def bar(x):
    if x < 0:
        return None
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

```py
# Wrong:

def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)

def bar(x):
    if x < 0:
        return
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция может вернуть `None`, если из переданных параметров невозможно вернуть вычисленное значение.

Но глаавное надо учесть, что эта невозможность вернуть значение не является ошибкой, в противном случае надо вызывать исключение.